# Error: "No row with the given identifier exists[ITELnetERP.Model.Continent#AF ]" in C# with Castle

Tags: c#, postgresql, activerecord, castle

I am starting a new project using C# + Castle ActiveRecord with PostgreSQL. I have this two classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Castle.ActiveRecord;

namespace ITELnetERP.Model
{
    [ActiveRecord("countries", Table = "countries")]
    public class Country : ActiveRecordBase<Country>
    {
        private string _code;
        private string _iso3;
        private string _number;
        private string _name;
        private Continent _continent;
        private string _calling_code;
        private DateTime _created_at;
        private DateTime _updated_at;

        [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Assigned, Column = "code")]
        public string Code
        {
            get { return _code; }
            set { _code = value; }
        }

    [Property("iso3")]
    public string ISO3
    {
        get { return _iso3; }
        set { _iso3 = value; }
    }

    [Property("number")]
    public string Number
    {
        get { return _number; }
        set { _number = value; }
    }

    [Property("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [Property("calling_code")]
    public string CallingCode
    {
        get { return _calling_code; }
        set { _calling_code = value; }
    }

    [BelongsTo("continent_code")]
    public Continent Continent
    {
        get { return _continent; }
        set { _continent = value; }
    }

    [Property("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt
    {
        get { return _created_at; }
        set { _created_at = value; }
    }

    [Property("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt
    {
        get { return _updated_at; }
        set { _updated_at = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Castle.ActiveRecord;
using System.Collections;

namespace ITELnetERP.Model
{
[ActiveRecord("continents")]
public class Continent : ActiveRecordBase<Continent>
{
    private string _code;
    private string _name;
    private DateTime _created_at;
    private DateTime _updated_at;
    private IList _countries = new ArrayList();

    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Assigned, Column = "code")]
    public string Code
    {
        get { return _code; }
        set { _code = value; }
    }

    [Property("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [HasMany(typeof(Country), Table = "countries", ColumnKey = "continent_code")]
    public IList Countries
    {
        get { return _countries; }
        set { _countries = value; }
    }

    [Property("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt
    {
        get { return _created_at; }
        set { _created_at = value; }
    }

    [Property("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt
    {
        get { return _updated_at; }
        set { _updated_at = value; }
    }
    }
}
```

on my startup file I have this (Note I am using PostgreSQL as DBMS):

```
 static void Main()
    {
        // Read Configuration for Database
        IDictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        properties.Add("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver");
        properties.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.Add("connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
        properties.Add("connection.connection_string", "Server=localhost;Port=5433;Database=ITELnet_ERP;Uid=itelnet_erp;Pwd=itelnet");
        properties.Add("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle");

        InPlaceConfigurationSource source = new InPlaceConfigurationSource();
        source.Add(typeof(ActiveRecordBase), properties);

        // Initialize Database
        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(source, GetActiveRecordTypes());

        // Start the Application
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

When I try to select all "Countries" from the database using following statement:

```
var countries = Country.FindAll();
foreach (Country country in countries)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Country Name: " + country.Name);
}
```

I get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException' occurred in Castle.ActiveRecord.dll

Additional information: Could not perform FindAll for Country

Image for more details:

[image: more details aboit the error]

What is wrong with my code?

How can I solve that?

Thanks for your attention

Regards
PS

Comment: someone can help me here, please

Comment: Ppl here are helpful, typically, but usually only if you showcase some effort on yourself.